# How to detect multiple square centers in a specific order? (OpenCV 3.4.6, C++) Edited

Tags: opencv

I am wondering if there is a way to detect centers of all squares, but in a specific order. I have already written the detection and storing of points but I need them to be detected in specific order.

I will provide an image and on that image there will be written (in paint) the specific order of detection.

![Detection order]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcSaF.jpg

Currently, it detects from bottom->up (4->3->2->1->6->5). I want order to be 1->2->3->4->5->6, like it says on the image.

The only idea I am currently having is to use push_back/push_front the stored points. Also, another idea I am having is to make 6 if statements that detect specific parts of image...like

```
if(rect_position[0]) 
  center_point[0] = rotatedRect.center
else if(rect_position[1])
  center_point[1] = rotatedRect.center
.
.
.
```

where *rect_position[0]* will hold x0, y0, x1, y1 (basically make another rectangle, and if detected point is inside that rectangle, write the point). Camera won't move, face will be static with small movement.

Also, I tought to use mouse to specify order, using ***void CallBackFunc***, but I am also not allowed to do that because professor wants detection to be automatic.

Anything will help: tutorial, hint, new idea,
Thank you very much.

I am storing points like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
  center_points[i] = rotatedRect.center;
}
```

Squares are detected using inRange and findContours functions and RotatedRect. I can provide more code if needed, I just need a solution.

Comment: Can you use the dlib library instead?

Comment: No, I am required to use OpenCV only for my bachelor thesis. We didn't use dlib library, only OpenCV, so I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: You could use differect colored rectangles, or some kind of pattern, so you know which rectangle is which? If you can safely assume that the face is always going to be facing the camera, then you could exploit the fact that the rectangles are not positioned symetrically in both axes, so you should be able to identify which one is which doing some maths with the centre coordinates.

Comment: You mean like template matching? 6 different templates and I specify which one is detected first? I wanted to do that, but position does change. Also, different colors means I will load 6 trackbars to detect, professor would not be pleased.

1) I need to capture ~300 frames (10 seconds video).
2) Detect centers of squares on all frames (images).
3) Save detected centers (write them in file).
4) Import file in Blender (3d modeling software) to use on face. 

I have done all, I just need order to be correct and to do some more research on how to write that .BVH script for blender.